# How to make this code work with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

My code is like this:

```
from PIL import Image        
from VideoCapture import Device                                                 
def cam_capture(usr):
    try:
        cam = Device()                              
        cam.saveSnapshot('%s//intruder.jpg'%(usr))
        del cam
    except:
        return
if __name__=='__main__':
    cam_capture('aninda')
```

the problem is when i execute this code it works just fine but when i make an exe with
py2exe then it doesn't save the image..I am on windows 7 and using python 2.7

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes while making the exe it says:the following file missing:['ICCprofile','_imagingagg','_sysconfigdata'].after that it still makes the exe file but when i run it it doesn't save any image